# How to make restrictions with hibernate criteria?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-criteria

I am beginner in using Hibernate and Criteria. I'm trying to make a condition to get information from database about " ALL PRODUCTS THAT HAVE THE SAME CATEGORY REFERENCE". These are the entities that I have and the method that I'm trying to create in DAO.

PRODUCT

```
@Entity
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

private Integer ref_Product;
private String name_Product;
private float price;
private String description;
private Date last_Update;

//--------------------------------//
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Category category;

public Category getCategory(){
    return category;    
}

public Integer getIdCategory(){
    return category.getRef_Category();

}

public void setCategory(Category cat){
    this.category=cat;
}
//--------------------------------//
```

CATEGORY

```
@Entity
public class Category {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

private Integer ref_Category;
private String name_Category;
public int getRef_Category() {
    return ref_Category;
}
public void setRef_Category(int ref_Category) {
    this.ref_Category = ref_Category;
}
public String getName_Category() {
    return name_Category;
}
public void setName_Category(String name_Category) {
    this.name_Category = name_Category;
}
public Category() {
}
public Category(String name_Category) {
    super();
    this.name_Category = name_Category;
}
```

}

FIND ALL PRODUCTS BY CATEGORY ID

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Product> findAllByCat(Integer id) {

    Criteria criteria= getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Product.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("?????", id));
    List<Product> list = (List<Product>) criteria.list();

    return list;
   }
```

What should I put in the first parameter of Restrictions to get what I want?

TEST JSP PAGE

```
<%@page import="org.apache.jasper.tagplugins.jstl.core.ForEach"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

 <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
 <%@ page import="com.e_com.model.*" %>
 <%@ page import="Service.*" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Category Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 align="center">Category Page</h1>

<% 


   ProductService productService = new ProductService();
   List<Product> listProduct= productService.findAllByCat(1);
 System.out.println(listProduct);

%>



<table  border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Reference</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Last Update</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Buy</th>
    </tr>

 <%
    for(Product p:listProduct){%>
        <tr>
        <td><%out.println(p.getRef_Product());%></td>
        <td><%out.println(p.getName_Product());%></td>
        <td><%out.println(p.getDescription());%></td>
        <td><%out.println(p.getLast_Update());%></td>
        <td><%out.println(p.getPrice());%></td>
        <td align="center"><a href="Cart?id=<%= p.getRef_Product() %>&action= ordernow">Order Now</a></td>


        </tr>
    <%}
    %> 

</table>
```

Here is the code that concerns ProductService

```
   public List<Product> findAllByCat(Integer id) {
            productDao.openCurrentSession();
            List<Product> products = productDao.findAllByCat(id);
            productDao.closeCurrentSession();
            return products;
        }
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the code into the question rather than add images. For two reasons 1)links to external sites eventually expire, making the question useless to others, and 2) it is much easier to help if folk can copy snippets of your code into answers if necessary.

Comment: @KLibby I put the code ;)

Comment: Using an ORM framework, tagging `[java-ee]` still using the maintenance-unfriendly Scriptlets. Any reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to create an alias for product as well as the category association. Then add the necessary restriction on category alias.

```
Criteria criteria= getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Product.class, "product");
criteria. createAlias("product.category","category");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("category.ref_Category", id));
// Below line ensures only distinct products are retrieved, no duplicates. 
// Useful in cases where OneToMany is configured EAGER or FETCH is JOIN. 
// You may or may not need this depending on your configuration.
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
List<Product> list = (List<Product>) criteria.list();
```